# Alexa/similarWeb traffic tracking on single-page application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, single-page-application, traffic-measurement

We have a single-page application build in angularJS, and are now facing the dilemma on how can Alexa/similarWeb properly track the traffic and user engagement within our classifieds sites. We figured out how to handle SEO and track with GA, but not with tools like Alexa.

Since these tools track page views among other things, we will likely take a dive in reported traffic when changing to SPA as they seem to lack any kind of dynamic JS tracking that google analytics provide.

Are there any good practices/tricks to make Alexa/SimilarWeb report correct traffic on angularJS SPA?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. Do you already use tracking but it is not working? What have you tried so far? I'm using Google Analytics and its working ok.

Comment: GA is not a problem, we solved that. We need to make traffic look right on Alexa/SimilarWeb because of the marketing purposes, but our site takes a hit in the reported traffic there due to it being SPA. Fewer page views, fewer real links, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work at SimilarWeb and I think the only workaround that will enable us to estimate your application's traffic accurately is to use our Google Analytics verification option. You can do so either publicly or anonymously, check the links on our site's footer for more info.